# Submitting an App to Apple wrote in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

Okay, I know what your thinking why, right?  My employer wants me to work on their app and submit it to Apple, but I told him the app has to be wrote in the most up to date OS.  Does anyone know where you can find a something that states your, iphone App must have the most up to date OS? He would to have some concrete proof, before they restart their project. I'm like 90% sure your app has to have the most recent OS, but I also am having troubles finding something from apple that says that.

thanks

Comment: As long as it runs under iOS6 it should work. Check for deprecated/removed methods

Comment: You mean build against the latest iOS version or deploy only onto the latest iOS version (very different things)? You need to build against the latest but can deploy against 'any'.

Comment: currently they are using an version 3.2.5 of xcode, for one. They want to make sure that if you have an older iphone that you can run their app, i think the last iphone that can run i0S6 is one of the iphone 3gs i think. Currently they have xcode only able to create apps with the highest compatibility of ios 4.2.

Comment: If I submitted their app the way it is, which is iOS 4.2 would apple reject it? Would it even run on iOS 6?

Answer (score 0):

Starting tomorrow (May 1st), all new apps and app updates must fully support the taller screen of the iPhone 5 and 5th gen iPod touch. In order to do this you need to be using Xcode 4.5 or later with a Base SDK of 6.0 or later. And this in turn means that the oldest Deployment Target you can support is iOS 4.3.

See https://developer.apple.com/news/ and look at the news items from March 21.

So you can still support iOS 4 but it must be 4.3 and later. You must have full retina support on all devices you support and you must fully support the taller iPhone/iPod touch screens.

To be honest, supporting 4.3 is virtually pointless at this point in time. Any device that can run 4.3 can run 5.1. And except for the iPad 1 and 3rd gen iPod touch, any device that can run iOS 5 can run iOS 6. So basically, there is no reason to support anything before iOS 5.1. Any user running 4.3 or 5.0 can update to at least 5.1 if not the latest 6.x.

In other words, starting May 1st, 2013, no new apps or app updates can support the iPhone 3G or older, or the first 2 iPod touches.

BTW - the following Wikipedia page has a good chart about what versions of iOS run on the different devices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

Comment: Don't legacy springs and struts apps work is many cases for the taller iPhone 5 screen without modification?

Comment: No, legacy apps run in letterbox mode on taller devices. You need to add the `Default-568h@2x.png` launch image to signal that the app supports the taller screens. With those in place, properly written screens should adapt to the new size. But of course that requires proper testing to be sure. Support for the taller launch images was added in Xcode 4.5 (I think that's the version).